# C#での電卓作成について

Tags: c#

現在C#で電卓を作成しているのですが、Funcを使用しても上手に動きません。

やりたいこととしては、`1*2*3`のような、連続した計算になります。
演算子ボタンを押したとき、答えが出るようにしたいです。

初めは演算子ボタンの中にイコールの処理を入れたのですが、Funcを使えば短く簡潔に書けると言われました。SUBとADDはまだ書き換えていません。クリアボタンを押したときの処理も書き換え中です。

以下が該当のコードになります。

```
  namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool isFirst = true;
        decimal num1 = 0;

        private void Number_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sign != arithmetic.undefined && isFirst) {
                num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textDisplay.Text);
                textDisplay.Text = "";
                isFirst = false;
            }
            if (textDisplay.TextLength == 12) {
                return;
            }
            textDisplay.Text =
               textDisplay.Text + ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
        private void Dot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (textDisplay.Text.IndexOf(".") >= 0) {
                return;
            }
            textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + ".";
        }

        enum arithmetic{
            undefined, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV
        };
        arithmetic sign = arithmetic.undefined;

        private void ADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (sign != arithmetic.undefined) {
                decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textDisplay.Text);
                decimal Result = 0;
                Result = num1 + num2;
                textDisplay.Text = Result.ToString();
            }
            sign = arithmetic.ADD;
            isFirst = true;
        }
        private void SUB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sign != arithmetic.undefined) {
                decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textDisplay.Text);
                decimal Result = 0;
                Result = num1 - num2;
                textDisplay.Text = Result.ToString();
            }
            sign = arithmetic.SUB;
            isFirst = true;
        }
        private void MUL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> MUL = (num1, num2) => {
                return num1 * num2;
            };
            sign = arithmetic.MUL;
            isFirst = true;          
        }  

        private void DIV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Func<decimal,decimal,decimal> DIV = (num1,num2) => {
                return num1 / num2;
            }
;            sign = arithmetic.DIV;
            isFirst = true;
        }
        private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textDisplay.Text);
            decimal Result = 0;
            try {
                switch (sign) {
                    case arithmetic.ADD:
                        Result = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case arithmetic.SUB:
                        Result = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case arithmetic.MUL:
                        Result = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case arithmetic.DIV:
                        Result = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(DivideByZeroException) {
                textDisplay.Text = "0では割れません";{
                    return;
                }
            }

            textDisplay.Text = Result.ToString();
            isFirst = true;
　　　　　　　  if (textDisplay.TextLength >= 13) {
                textDisplay.Text = "桁数超過";  

                this.button0.Enabled = false;
                this.button1.Enabled = false;
                this.button2.Enabled = false;
                this.button3.Enabled = false;
                this.button4.Enabled = false;
                this.button5.Enabled = false;
                this.button6.Enabled = false;
                this.button7.Enabled = false;
                this.button8.Enabled = false;
                this.button9.Enabled = false;
                this.buttonEq.Enabled = false;
                this.Dot.Enabled = false;
                this.ADD.Enabled = false;
                this.SUB.Enabled = false;
                this.MUL.Enabled = false;
                this.DIV.Enabled = false;
               }
        }
        private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            this.button0.Enabled = true;
            this.button1.Enabled = true;
            this.button2.Enabled = true;
            this.button3.Enabled = true;
            this.button4.Enabled = true;
            this.button5.Enabled = true;
            this.button6.Enabled = true;
            this.button7.Enabled = true;
            this.button8.Enabled = true;
            this.button9.Enabled = true;
            this.buttonEq.Enabled = true;
            this.Dot.Enabled = true;
            this.ADD.Enabled = true;
            this.SUB.Enabled = true;
            this.MUL.Enabled = true;
            this.DIV.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: プログラムのコードというのは、他のいろいろな部分と密接に関連しながら動くもので、コードの断片だけ見せられても、何がどう悪いか、どうすれば「上手に」動くものかわかりません。今この質問を読んでいる人間は、この質問内に書かれたことしか知らないのです。そういった人間にもわかるような説明を心がけてください。あなたの電卓アプリの画面にはどんな要素があるのですか? 表示は? ボタンは? あなたのコードの中で`sign`ってなんですか? `arithmetic`とは? `isFirst`ってどこでどう使われているんですか? そう言ったことを明らかにした上で、「現在はこういう操作をするとこういう動作になってしまう」「本当はこんな操作をするとこうなってほしい」という事柄をできるだけ具体的に記述するようにしてください。電卓程度のアプリならコードのほとんど全部を掲載しても目くじら立てるほどの量にもならないと思います。ご自身の質問は「編集」から修正が可能なはずですので、必要な情報を付け足し、何がどうなってほしいのか、具体的な質問に書き換えてみてください。

Comment: 関係ありそうな投稿 https://teratail.com/questions/184217

Answer (score 2):

画面には結果/入力中の数値を表示するためのTextBox(`textDisplay`)が1つと、[0]〜[9]の数値ボタン、[.][+][-][×][÷][=][Clear]のボタンがある。

現在のあなたのコードでの動作はこんな感じ:

```
操作 TextBoxの表示    
[1] 1
[*] (変化無し)
[2] 2
[*] (変化無し)
[3] 3
[=] 6 (2*3の結果が表示される)
```

と言った感じでしょうか。手元にWinFormの実行環境がないので、コードだけ見て書いていますから、誤りがあったら知らせてください。

望まれる動作はこんな感じ:

```
操作 TextBoxの表示    
[1] 1
[*] (変化無し)
[2] 2
[*] 2 (1*2の結果が表示される)
[3] 3
[=] 6 (2*3の結果が表示される…ここでの`2`は1回目の計算結果)
```

と言ったところでしょうか。

---

『「現在はこういう操作をするとこういう動作になってしまう」「本当はこんな操作をするとこうなってほしい」という事柄をできるだけ具体的に記述する』と言うのは例えばですが、上記のようなことを記述してほしいと言うことです。

私のこの回答は一部推定で書いているので、使い物にならないかもしれませんが、このレベルでどんな動作にしたいのかを記述していただければ、お望みの回答を書けるような方はたくさんいらっしゃると思います。

---

あなたの`MUL_Click`には、何らかの計算を行ってその結果を表示するようなコードは一切ないのですから、現在の動作は当たり前の結果だと思いませんか?

演算キーが押されたときには1個前の計算を行わないといけないのですから、それをどこかに覚えていないといけません。あなたのコードの中では`sign`なんてフィールドがあるようですが、`sign`に「1個前の計算」なんて意味はありませんからやめた方が良いですね。

例えば`Func`(`FUNC`ではないはずです。大文字小文字を区別する言語を使うのですから、その辺の感覚はしっかり持ってください)を使うんならこんなフィールドとメソッドを付け加えてやります。

```
        private Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> pendingOperation = null;

        private void doPendingOperation() {
            if( pendingOperation != null ) {
                try {
                    decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textDisplay.Text);
                    decimal result = pendingOperation(num1, num2);
                    textDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                catch(DivideByZeroException) {
                    textDisplay.Text = "0では割れません";
                    return;
                }
                if (textDisplay.TextLength >= 13) {
                    textDisplay.Text = "桁数超過";  

                    this.button0.Enabled = false;
                    this.button1.Enabled = false;
                    this.button2.Enabled = false;
                    this.button3.Enabled = false;
                    this.button4.Enabled = false;
                    this.button5.Enabled = false;
                    this.button6.Enabled = false;
                    this.button7.Enabled = false;
                    this.button8.Enabled = false;
                    this.button9.Enabled = false;
                    this.buttonEq.Enabled = false;
                    this.Dot.Enabled = false;
                    this.ADD.Enabled = false;
                    this.SUB.Enabled = false;
                    this.MUL.Enabled = false;
                    this.DIV.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

演算ボタンを押したら必ずこのメソッドを呼ぶとともに`pendingOperation`を更新します。

```
        private void MUL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            doPendingOperation();
            Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> mul = (num1, num2) => {a
                return num1 * num2;
            };
            pendingOperation = mul;
            isFirst = true;          
        }  

        private void DIV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            doPendingOperation();
            Func<decimal,decimal,decimal> div = (num1,num2) => {
                return num1 / num2;
            };
            pendingOperation = div;
            isFirst = true;
        }
```

イコールボタンを押した時の処理もほとんどこのメソッドを呼ぶだけで済みます。

```
        private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            doPendingOperation();
            pendingOperation = null;
            isFirst = true;
        }
```

実行どころか、コンパイルが通るかどうかも確認していませんので、あちこち細かい修正が必要になるかもしれませんが、試してみてください。

また、「これは私が期待する動作とは違う」と言う場合には、ご質問を編集して、できるだけ具体的にどんな動作にしたいのかを記述してください。

---

**修正**

コメントでいただいた状態での動作が確認できました。「`sign`は使わない」なんて上記の回答中に書いたのに、`Number_Click`中で`sign`を参照している部分を放置してしまっていました。

```
        private void Number_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                var str1 = textDisplay.Text == "" ? "0" : textDisplay.Text;
                num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(str1);
                textDisplay.Text = "";
                isFirst = false;
            }
            if (textDisplay.TextLength == 12)
            {
                return;
            }
            textDisplay.Text =
               textDisplay.Text + ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
```

…とでも修正すれば、とりあえず計算自体ができないなんてことはなくなるかと思います。お試しください。

(すでにお分かりかと思いますが、ADD, SUB, Clearについては、何も手を入れていません。ご自身で修正していってください。)

Comment: お力を貸していただき、ありがとうございます。実際に試したところ、計算自体ができなくなってしまい、コードの位置など変えてみたり、知っている範囲で付け加えてもみましたがやはりできなくなってしまいました。６を２回押すと６６となり、演算子ボタンを押すと０になってしまいます。

Comment: 未テストのコードお試しいただき恐縮です。試された操作は[6][6](この時点で表示は「66」)[*](この時点で表示が「0」)と言う風にボタンを3回押した、と言うことでよろしいでしょうか?

Comment: すみません、ミスがありました。6*6と押すと、テキストボックスの表記が６６になり、四回目に*を押すとその表示が０になってしまいます。

Comment: @hntmsm55 さん、ご確認ありがとうございます。さらに一つ確認です。「コードの位置など変えてみたり、知っている範囲で付け加えてもみました」とありますが、それらすべての修正は元に戻した(あなたがご質問にあげられたコード+この回答に示された修正以外の変更は一切行われていない状態)上での挙動をお示しいただいているでしょうか。あなたが独自に行われた修正については、読み手に対して一切の情報はありません。再度ご確認ください。

Comment: 返信いただきありがとうございます。OOperさんのおっしゃる通りです。全てを元に戻した上、上記コードを入力した際の挙動になります。

Comment: @hntmsm55 さん、ご確認ありがとうございます。現在古いWindowsマシンの埃を払って動作確認できる状態まで持って行っている途中です。ご報告できるような事柄が整理できれば、回答を更新させていただきます。

Comment: OOPerさん、本当にありがとうございました！！！修正につきましては、ぼちぼちとやっていきます。